# How to execute Hadoop Jar with external properties

Tags: java, hadoop, properties, hdfs

I have a jar application that works with an external properties file. The file is used so that the user can override default properties. The default and core properties are part of the build so no problem there.

Normaly I would do something like one of theese:

```
java -jar MyAwesomeApp.jar user.properties
```

OR

```
java -jar MyAwesomeApp.jar -Dmyapp.userproperties=user.properties
```

But with hadoop, the jar gets executed inside the hadoop framework like this

```
/bin/hadoop jar MyAwesomeApp.jar input output
```

And no matter where I put the -D I can't get the value via System.getProperty(...). The properties is not set. The hadoop documentation said that -D is a GENERIC OPTION and is set after the command. But if I do so I get an error that -D is not a valid jar file (duh...)

I aim to keep the application as clean as possible...so I only want to pass the user configuration as a parameter as a last resort, i.e.

```
/bin/hadoop jar MyAwesomeApp.jar input output user.properties
```

I hope someone can tell me what I have to do to get the -D working :/
Hadoop is running pseudo distributed so I am actually using HDFS too...

Comment: run export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dmyapp.userproperties=user.properties" before running the hadoop jar command. You can also look for GenericOptionsParser at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/GenericOptionsParser.html

Comment: What is the export doing exactly? I thought exports just set a certain value for later use. Would I have to use it in the call then?
The Link was the one I was using at first. It sais there the call should be
bin/hadoop command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]
But if I do the 
bin/hadoop jar -Dmyapp.userproperties=user.properties MyAwesomeApp.jar
then I get an error saing that -Dmyapp.userproperties is not a valid jar file...

Comment: Just try running the export command in your terminal before running the hadoop jar command. export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dmyapp.userproperties=user.properties" will set the options in System properties. You can simply access the value using System.getProperty("myapp.userproperties") in your java code.

Comment: Ok that seems to work...but this export is still there even when the application is finished...that doesn't feel too clean to me...can I unset that export?